# How to multiple tabs for different users in same browser using node js

Tags: node.js, session, session-cookies

How can i manage different session for different users in same browser with different tabs in node js.

Comment: I'm currently looking for the same feature

Comment: It's not a straight forward problem. I've not managed to get it to work properly, yet, but I'm attempting to use a property in sessionstorage to record which user a tab is logged in as, and localstorage for recording both the credentials for each user successfully logged in and which user was most recently logged in. This might work better for long-lived credentials.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to open a few 'incognito' or 'private' windows. You could also use Chromes multi-profile feature: https://www.chromium.org/user-experience/multi-profiles